# Fiddler2 - How do I URlDecode the Request body for Viewing?

Tags: fiddler, urldecode

I'm using Fiddler to debug some particularly painful AJAX code, and in the POST requests that are being sent across to the server the Request BODY is UrlEncoded. This leads to me having to cut and paste the text into an online app to UrlDecode the text into the JSON object for the request. There has to be a better way to do this.

Does anyone know how I can make fiddler automatically URLDecode the body of the POST Request?

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can simply press `CTRL+E` to decode locally. But depending on the format, you may also be able to use the WebForms Inspector.

Answer (score 1):

Fiddler can manipulate the HTTP request and response in any way you like:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23615119/264181