# Can I make Fiddler unzip outbound traffic?

Tags: proxy, gzip, fiddler

In order to replicate a problem some users are having with my application, I need to simulate a corporate proxy server which decompresses GZIP'd http traffic and doesn't recompress it before passing it to the destination server.  The users are getting the error "the magic number in the GZIP header is incorrect" and it's my suspicion that the proxy server is not re-zipping the decompressed GZIPed traffic.

Is there a way I can simulate this using Fiddler? Specifically, I think I need to simulate proxys decompressing the body and perhaps not altering the headers to match.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Fiddler can manipulate the HTTP request and response in any way you like.

First, please confirm that your application GZIP's the **request** body. While compressing the **response** is very common, compressing the request is very uncommon for a number of reasons.

After that, you can do the following:

1. In Fiddler, click `Rules` > `Customize Rules`.
2. Scroll to `OnBeforeRequest`.
3. Inside the method, add the following code:

   `if (oSession.oRequest.headers.ExistsAndContains("Content-Encoding", "gzip"))
   {
      oSession.utilDecodeRequest(); // Decompress request and remove header
      oSession.oRequest["Content-Encoding"] = "gzip";  // Put header back
      oSession["ui-backcolor"] = "yellow"; // Mark the session
   }`
4. Save the script.

Comment: Yes, I have custom code to compress the request (which I'm now regretting putting in as it seems proxy servers are buggy when handling compressed requests!). However my "request" is several MB of XML and not compressing it would dramatically slow down the application. I am considering removing all my custom request GZipping and instead sending over HTTPS (which should compress everything anyway).

Comment: I don't know if my application code is wrong, but if it isn't then it appears that two different proxy servers actually decompress the request body while leaving the Content-encoding header set to "gzip" :(

Comment: HTTPS doesn't "compress everything anyway" but it does typically prevent proxy servers from seeing the traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to:

Recenly, I found that the GZIP zip/unzip feature in fiddler does not work properly. There are applications which are based on HTTP protocol and also zip HTTP Requests and Responses with GZIP format. So I decided to write some script using Fiddler Script Editor for converting and extracting Requests that are in GZIP format. Here is the code, copy this to the CustomRules.js file (Rules---->Customize Rules)

http://yossi-yakubov.blogspot.fr/2010/05/fiddler-gzip-issue.html